# Confusion about set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It has been a while of leaving school. I have two questions about set and list.

A list contains elements in some order; they can be repeated. E.g. $\{1,2,3,4,2\}$ is a list, and $\{1,3,2,2,4\}$ is another list.

How about set? Set doesn't have an order. But can elements in a set be repeated?

Comment: No, in a set you are not allowed to repeat things. This is allowed in so-called *multisets*.

Answer (score 4):

It's valid to repeat elements in set notation (fx $\{1,3,2,2,4\}$) but that doesn't make a difference. The set is characterized only by which elements it contains and which it doesn't. For example the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is the same as $\{1,3,2,2,4\}$ (because both contains 1, 2, 3 and 4, but no other elements).